# How to use Globe.gl React component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, three.js, webgl

I asked a similar request in the Git Repo as well here, https://github.com/vasturiano/react-globe.gl.

I have an app that uses the react component exported by this project. It depends on three.js and WebGL to work. It is an extension of this repo by the same author, https://github.com/vasturiano/globe.gl.

I made a beautiful web app with these libraries and all works as expected, on the web, but I want to extend this to a mobile app built on react native as well.

I have tried a simple port but get an error from the CSS2DRenderer trying to access the document object which clearly doesn't exist on a mobile app.

I tried using expo GLView [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/gl-view/), but could not for the life me figure out where to start on the context creation function to be able to port the three globe to it.

My question is, based on the Repo's I have shared above, what is the best approach to implementing the Globe in React Native?

I would also take any alternatives that I could do drag/zoom Globe with dynamic plot points and interactive functions (click basically).

For a quick setup to recreate the project, I am working an out of the box react native application setup

`npm i react-globe.gl`

Pop below component inside of a `View` in the app.js and import the Globe from above library. Provide an empty array for `hexBinPointsData`

```
  <Globe
    globeImageUrl="//unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/earth-night.jpg"
    bumpImageUrl="//unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/earth-topology.png"
    backgroundImageUrl="//unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/night-sky.png"
    hexBinPointsData={plotData}
    hexAltitude={0.1}
    hexBinResolution={4}
    hexBinMerge={false}
  />
```

Expected error: Document variable cannot be found. In the CSS2DRenderer.js file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: any luck finding a solution to get react-globe.gl working on a Native setting?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work @JonoTho'ra! I have a nice web app that I never turned into a mobile app :(

Comment: just following this up, maybe anyone knows: are there any alternative good react native libraries maybe, that would still display an interactive globe similar to globe.js?